# How to insert data without duplication

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
cus_id int, NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT,
gov_id int, NOT NULL UNIQUE,
name varchar(64), NOT NULL
address varchar(128), NOT NULL
);
```

When I need to insert data, I first look at the `gov_id` a customer has given me and check if I already have the data in my table. If I don't, then I insert the row. Otherwise, I update the `name` and `address` of the row.

I know I can use `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but the thing is, `Bob`'s `cus_id` might be `123` and `Sam`'s `gov_id` might be `123`. So when I try to insert `Sam` (a new customer), MySQL might think its a duplicate, when it really isn't. What are my options here? How do I fix this.

Also is there any possible way that I can get back the `cus_id` after I have done the operation. So if I insert the row, I get back the `cus_id` and if I update the row, I still get back the `cus_id`. While this is a MySQL question, my implementation is in PHP

**Old method I used (which has potential for duplicates):**

I would first check if the customer exists

```
SELECT cus_id FROM customers WHERE gov_id = 123;
```

At this point there is a potential for duplicate. Anyways If the customer exists  I run

```
UPDATE customers SET name = "Bob", address = "123 something rd" WHERE cus_id=555;
```

Otherwise I run

```
INSERT INTO customers (gov_id, name, address) VALUES (123, "Sam", "567 pizza st");
```

However, at the end of the day, when I use the old method, I would always have the `cus_id` of the customer after I run the above operations. If they exist, I could get the `cus_id` from the `select` statement. If they didn't exist, I would get the `cus_id` from the `insert` statement.

Comment: Grown up companies mitigate such risks by allocating customer numbers,account numbers etc in way which makes screw ups less likely(though not impossible) - Think your bank account number and think check digits.

Answer (score 1):

I change your create table sql because it seems contain some error in my sandbox:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
    `cus_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `gov_id` int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `address` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`cus_id`)
);
```

I'm not sure why you say `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` couldn't work in your place. I think `cus_id` and `gov_id` are different key and they shouldn't impact with each other.

Anyway, I still choose use `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, if there are any misunderstanding, please let me know:

```
SET @update_id := 0;
insert into `customers` (gov_id, name, address) values (123, "Sam1", "567 pizza st")
on duplicate key update name = "Bob", address = "123 something rd", cus_id = (@update_id := cus_id);
SELECT
case
   when @update_id = 0 then LAST_INSERT_ID()
   when @update_id > 0 then @update_id
end as cus_id;
```

The following are the insert result when cus_id of 133 is already in customers table, we want to insert a new custerm who's gov_id is 133 too.

```
mysql> select * from `customers`;
+--------+--------+------+------------------+
| cus_id | gov_id | name | address          |
+--------+--------+------+------------------+
|    123 |    122 | Sam  | 567 pizza st     |
|    124 |    123 | Bob  | 123 something rd |
|    128 |    124 | Bob  | 123 something rd |
|    131 |    125 | Sam1 | 567 pizza st     |
|    132 |    126 | Sam1 | 567 pizza st     |
|    133 |    127 | Sam1 | 567 pizza st     |
+--------+--------+------+------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @update_id := 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into `customers` (gov_id, name, address) values (133, "Sam1", "567 pizza st")
    -> on duplicate key update name = "Bob", address = "123 something rd", cus_id = (@update_id := cus_id);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    -> case
    ->    when @update_id = 0 then LAST_INSERT_ID()
    ->    when @update_id > 0 then @update_id
    -> end as cus_id;
+--------+
| cus_id |
+--------+
|    134 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from `customers`;
+--------+--------+------+------------------+
| cus_id | gov_id | name | address          |
+--------+--------+------+------------------+
|    123 |    122 | Sam  | 567 pizza st     |
|    124 |    123 | Bob  | 123 something rd |
|    128 |    124 | Bob  | 123 something rd |
|    131 |    125 | Sam1 | 567 pizza st     |
|    132 |    126 | Sam1 | 567 pizza st     |
|    133 |    127 | Sam1 | 567 pizza st     |
|    134 |    133 | Sam1 | 567 pizza st     |
+--------+--------+------+------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What if there is a `cus_id` of `123`. I have a new customer with a `gov_id` of `123`. If I try inserting my new customer, `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY` MAY CHOOSE `cus_id` to be the key, rather than `gov_id`

Comment: I still don't understand your point. when executing "insert into `customers` (gov_id, name, address) values (123, "Sam1", "567 pizza st")", mysql will know that cus_id is not given, and it will genereate cus_id by itself. Therefore, no matter what cus_id value existed in your table, it couldn't conflict caused by cus_id. Only when your will set both  cus_id and gov_id at the same time, mysql could have problem of choose key.

Answer (score 0):

to prevent duplication you can use unique index with both member
for example like this -> make unique index on (name, gov_id) so you will never see duplicate row with same name and same gove_id but you could have another row with same name and same gov_id

and here is another tricky faster way to do that

```
UPDATE table.customers SET (...) WHERE gove_id='SomeValue'
IF ROW_COUNT()=0
    INSERT INTO table.customers(...) VALUES (...)
```

Comment: What about the part of my question where I always need the `cus_id` after the operation. How do I always have the `cus_id` at the end?

Comment: the best way is using stored procedure! just look here -> `https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx/` and another option is using two line query ~  its simple just a select line after last line, like this 
 `SELECT @cus_id;`